# Debugging Excel macro through Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: debugging, excel, vb6, breakpoints, vba

I have VB6 code that executes various Excel macros. I set my breakpoints in VB6 and in the the Excel macro, then begin debugging in the VB6 application. When it reaches (a breakpoint) the statement to execute the macro, it skips over the command and continue traversing through my VB6 code. I was expecting it to jump to Excel and began debugging the Excel macro. Is there some configuration or trick, to debug an Excel macro that is being called from a VB6 application?

Comment: Can you put the calling code (or equivalent) in VBA instead and run it from there? Then you're debugging in a single environment.

Comment: That would make sense and make life easier. But I just joined a Dev Team that created this application several years ago. I'm not sure what the original Developers were thinking besides over-complicating processes.

Comment: If the VBA code has to do a lot of processing and it accesses the Excel file a large number of times then it will likely run faster than the equivalent VB code used to automate Excel, since VBA doesn't need to marshal anything across process boundaries (my understanding IANACS). Maybe that's why they set it up like that.

Answer (score 0):

When VB6 executes the its own code, it allows the programmer using the IDE to set breakpoints and give control to user when the execution has reached those said breakpoints. However, setting breakpoints in Excel will only benefit you if *you (the programmer)* have executed the macro from Excel interface. Which is not the case when VB6 is in charge of firing up Excel and telling it to execute the macros within the workbook.

Here is what you can do:

migrate all of the macro code to VB6. It is fairly easy, you just need to add few words here and there like this

```
'In Excel macro:
Activecell.Offset(0,1).Value = "my value"
```

so if we want to migrate this line of macro to VB6:

```
'In VB6 you must declare an instance of EXCEL application:

Dim EX as Excel.Application
EX.Workbooks.Open('c:\my_excel_file.xls')
EX.Sheets(0).Activate  'Go to the first sheet

'Then you are back to business:

EX.ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value = "my vlaue"

'But don't forget to close and dispose of EX instance afterwards.

EX.Activeworkbook.Close  'Check save options
EX.Quit
Set EX = Nothing
```

After you have migrated all of the macros functionality to VB6, you can set breakpoints in VB6 and you will have all the control over the execution and will be able to debug the code as you intended to do.

Comment: I am working with a full fledged vb6 application. I can't really migrate my macros to my VB6 code. Tedious and time-consuming because the macros are very large. Isn't there like a checkbox I can select or a command to use while debugging?